# What do elisp expression (1+ (buffer-size)) and (+ 1 (buffer-size)) mean?

Tags: emacs, lisp, expression, prefix

I'm very very new in elisp and just started learning it. I have seen the following expressions in the document:

```
(1+ (buffer-size))
(+ 1 (buffer-size))
```

What do they mean? As I know elisp use prefix notation, so the second one should be correct one. But both of them can be executed without any errors. The first one is from the documentation of `point-max` function.

Thanks.

Comment: `1+` is a function.  `+` is a function.  `buffer-size` is a function.  `M-x describe-function RET buffer-size RET` and `M-x describe-function RET 1+ RET` and `M-x describe-function RET + RET`

Comment: `C-h f RET 1+ RET`. `C-h f RET + RET`.

Answer (score 4):

The token `1+` is an identifier which denotes a symbol. This symbol has a binding as a function, and so `(1+ arg)` means "call the `1+` function, with the value of `arg` as its argument). The `1+` function returns `1` plus the value of its argument.

The syntax `(+ 1 arg)` is a different way to achieve that effect. Here the function is named by the symbol `+`.  The `+` function receives two arguments which it adds together.

In many mainstream programming languages popular today, the tokenization rules are such that there is no difference between `1+` and `1 +`: both of these denote a numeric constant followed by a `+` token. Lisp tokenization is different. Languages in the Lisp family usually support tokens that can contain can contain digits and non-alpha-numeric characters.  I'm looking at the Emacs Lisp reference manual and do not see a section about the logic which the `read` function uses to convert printed representations to objects.  Typically, "Lispy" tokenizing behavior is something like this: token is scanned first without regard for what kind of token it is based on accumulating characters which are valid token constituents, stopping at a character which is not a token constituent. For instance when the input is `abcde(f`, the token that will be extracted is `abcde`. The `(` character terminates the token (and stays in the input stream). Then, the resulting clump of characters `abcde` is re-examined and classified, converted to an object based on what it looks like, according to the rules of the given Lisp dialect. Across Lisp dialects, we can broadly depend on a token of all alphabetic characters to denote a symbol, and a token of all digits (possibly with a leading sign) to denote an integer. `1+` has a trailing `+` though, which is different!